# Customizable tables in Stata 17: Can I add number of failures?

Tags: stata, cox-regression

I am using Stata's new collection tool to create a table (Stata 17.0). I have completed the walkthrough https://blog.stata.com/2021/09/02/customizable-tables-in-stata-17-part-6-tables-for-multiple-regression-models/ and was able to get a table with p-value, sd, and CI.

I created it using this code

```
collect _r_b _r_p _r_se _r_ci,  ///
    name(model3) ///
    tag(model[(2)]) ///     
    : stcox i.tertile age_at_baseline initial_dose female_sex
```

It is a Cox hazard model, and I would like to add "Number of failures"

After running the above code, I can type `collect label list result, all` and see it included in 'level labels' as 'N_fail'. However, when I add it to my code it will not work.

```
collect create model3

collect _r_b _r_p _r_se _r_ci N_fail,   /// THIS TELLS STATA WHAT VARS YOU WANT
    name(model3) ///
    tag(model[(1)]) ///     THIS STORES THE OUTPUT INTO A NEW DIMENSION
    : stcox i.tertile
```

The error code

```
N_fail not found
r(111);
```